# importerror no module named tensorflow windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

```
import tensorflow as tf Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-41389fad42b5>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I am getting the following error after installation of tensorflow in anaconda using windows. I have followed the tensorflow installation steps

At first it was running properly but when i tried to uninstall and reinstall tensorflow, this error pops up. I tried uninstalling Anaconda itself and reinstalling but was of no help. Tensorflow is getting installed but when i try the import step it shows the above error.

Comment: Can you specify OS?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: and which python do you have?

Comment: Python 3.5 but my Anaconda Spyder version is 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Python 3.6 is incompatible with tensorflow and had to create tensorflow environment for python 3.5.

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5 anaconda
```

Activated it in command prompt and launched spyder from it which changed my python version to 3.5. Now was able to import tensorflow properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed tensorflow using Anaconda inside an Anaconda environment, you will need to activate this environment. Only then can you import tensorflow.

Comment: I had activated the environment, installed tensorflow and then tried the import. But still i had got the error.

Comment: Can you check `pip list` inside your environment to check if it shows tensorflow in the installed items list?

Comment: C:\>activate tensorflow

(tensorflow) C:\>pip list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
appdirs (1.4.3)
numpy (1.12.0)
packaging (16.8)
pip (9.0.1)
protobuf (3.2.0)
pyparsing (2.2.0)
setuptools (34.3.2)
six (1.10.0)
tensorflow-gpu (1.0.1)
wheel (0.29.0)

Comment: The above displays the list in the environment and you could see tensorflow-gpu (1.0.1)